# add method cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
if (findViewById(fragment_container) != null) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
    NameFragment firstFragment = new NameFragment();

    firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    switch (getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit());
}
```

I have problem in proceeding with the above part. where **.add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit()** method in last line cannot be resolved as indicated by Android Studio.

Comment: You are using the Support Fragment Manager. Is the fragment that you want to add also from the Support lib? I.e. does it have namespace `android.support.v4.app.` or `android.app`?

Comment: yes i'm using android.support.v4.app.